# How can I reformat API results into a dictionary then use that dictionary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an assignment where I need to key an API using a key that cannot be used by default. Currently, I'm using getJSON to pull data from an API as seen in the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/manifests/curiosity?api_key=DEMO_KEY", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

This makes sense, but I'm stuck from here. Essentially, I'd like to reformat the API results and store them in a dictionary so I can key the results using "sol". Ideally, the dictionary would only contain the key "sol", its value, and the key "cameras", and its values for every section within photos as seen in the API.

Additionally, how would you then go about keying the dictionary using a sol value, and returning the cameras associated with that sol value?

**EDIT:**
The code below works great, but I'm not seeing what I would need to put after everything to use camera globally.

```
        let new_dict = { "sol": {}, "cameras": {} };
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/manifests/curiosity?api_key=0L4UJKm4YYvddR1QdZdCihRwQIqKBGrPErgFqUsw", function(data){
                let photos = data["photo_manifest"]["photos"];
                let sol_arr = [];

                for(x in photos){
                    let photo = photos[x];
                    let sol = photo.sol;
                    let cameras = photo.cameras;

                    sol_arr.push(sol);
                    new_dict["cameras"][sol] = cameras;
                }
                new_dict["sol"] = sol_arr;
                
                let sol_value = 1;
                let camera = new_dict["cameras"][sol_value];
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/manifests/curiosity?api_key=DEMO_KEY", function(data){
    
    let photos = data["photo_manifest"]["photos"];



    let new_dict = { "sol" : {}, "cameras": {} };

    let sol_arr = [];

    for(x in photos){
 
        let photo = photos[x];

        let sol = photo.sol;
        let cameras = photo.cameras;

        sol_arr.push(sol);
        new_dict["cameras"][sol] = cameras;
        
    }

    new_dict["sol"] = sol_arr;

});
```

for keying the dictionary using a sol value, you just need to put sol value
like

```
let sol_value = 1;
console.log(new_dict["cameras"][sol_value]); //this contains the cameras with the sol value 1
```

Comment: This works great! So now, how would I go about pulling an individual camera out of the dictionary after I pass in whatever sol value I want?

Comment: ```let sol_value = 1;
    let camera = new_dict["cameras"][sol_value];
    console.log( 'Cameras found: ' + camera.join(',') );
``` or you may want to loop through them: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript.html

Comment: I'm having trouble accessing the camera output globally. Defining the variables outside the function and then running console.log(camera[0]), etc. is giving me an error.

Comment: @gskn13 if want to access it globally, move the ```let new_dict = { "sol" : {}, "cameras": {} };``` before the ```$.getJSON``` call. Check this out https://livecodestream.dev/post/2020-07-25-understanding-variables-scope-and-hoisting-in-javascript/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qn2b3f8w/ Like this right? I'm still getting an error. If I print to console doing camera[0] or camera.join(',') the console says it cannot read 0 or join or undefined.

Comment: Oh. that is because this code ```let sol_value = 1;
let camera = new_dict["cameras"][sol_value];
console.log('Cameras found: ' + camera.join(','));``` gets executed before the the getJSON finished loading. It needs to be called after ```new_dict["sol"] = sol_arr;```. Also in your jsfiddle you need to add the jquery library so you won't get ```Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined``` error.

Comment: Check out the edit I made to the post with the code. I'm still not sure what I can put after all that code to then use camera globally.